# what does the θ means in this case (machine learning)

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

[image]
I am reading Murphy but I have struggled with θ. 
why unsupervised learning is unconditional density estimation.
why unsupervised learning is not conditional on θ.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Would you please provide the quotation as text, rather than an image - because, among other reasons, images give trouble to the blind or partially sighted - ; & give a full reference for "Murphy".

Comment: In supervised, $y_i$ is a true outcome for each object, while in unsupervised, there is only the distribution of $x_i$.  In other words, for each $i$th object, in unsupervised, all you know is $x_i$, whereas in supervised, for each object $x_i$ there is a $y$-value or $y_i$, which can be a continuous outcome or class membership.  For example, $x_i$ could be caloric intake per day, while $y_i$ is the outcome weight for the given caloric intake.   If $y$ is continuous, it's a regression problem, if $y$ is collapsed into categories, it's a classification problem.